# Using MySQL with Rails (Building Blog in 15 Min.)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am running through the Rails blog in 15 minutes tutorial and want to use MySQL instead of Sqlite. I have MySQL installed. And I created the app with the -d mysql switch.

Here is my error message when I attempt to scaffold:
 "Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 5.5.27 but the client library is 5.6.23. (RuntimeError)"

Based on this I believe I have the incorrect gemfile. I cannot seem to find the one that I need to use however. I used the command (gem install mysql2). Surely this is simple, no?

Comment: Have you tried to put `gem 'mysql2'` in Gemfile and run a `bundle` command? Also, maybe you have different versions of MySQL in your machine. Try to uninstall all mysql2 gems and then re-install.

Answer (score 1):

Yes @Daniel Clukier is correct it seems that your Mysql client version doesn't match with your mysql client gem version. Try this command

`bundle update`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile and run `bundle` in your terminal and see if that fixes it.

Edit:

Try what Daniel said, `gem install mysql2` and then `bundle` and see if that fixes it. If not, try following this RichOnRails [link](http://richonrails.com/articles/getting-started-with-mysql-and-ruby-on-rails) here. It walks through making an app using the MySQL2 library.

Comment: I did so and it didn't work, but maybe you misread my problem? I'm not wanting to use Sqlite but MySQL...

Comment: Ah, I did indeed, sorry about that. I posted that about 2am my time working on a project, heh.